# How does `envelope` use the sliding window to determine RMS in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand how does the sliding window works when using the function `envelope` in MATLAB to calculate RMS (root mean square). I'm using the following code to reproduce the behavior of `envelope`:

```
rng(1);
Array = randn(1000,1);
window = 100;
limit = length(Array)-window;

%Part 2
for i=1:limit
    RMS(i) = rms(Array(i:i+window-1));
end
plot(RMS)
hold
```

I expect the part 2 in the code above to generate the same results as:

```
upper = envelope(Array(1:limit), 100, 'rms');
plot(upper)
```

However the first option (blue line) is displaced about 50 samples compared to the second option (red line):

[image]

I would like to understand how `envelope` determines the first samples.

Answer (score 1):

Since your window is not centered, you receive a shift of half-length of the chosen window.